How can I Wrap or Bend an object over a Cylinder?
I'm working with the snapping tool to project a shape onto the surface of a cylinder. It worked before, but now it doesn't, and I don't know what the difference is.

But when I use "Snap" it does something weird at the edges:

I'm not sure what's going on here. This was my 'good' result previously (now I'm not sure how to achieve the same result again):

I've tried almost every configuration in the snap menu, but this seems to be beyond my understanding. When I achieved what I wanted, I think I used Closest, Face Nearest, Align Rotation to Target, Include Non-Edited and Move.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

The Snap tool is really made to snap geometry or whole objects into place. I don't know what settings you have at the moment, it looks like it's snaping to the edges, but if you want to project an object onto another one and have it deform you should probably be using the Lattice modifier instead.

Create a Lattice and make it flat like in the image on the Lattice menu (the green grid tab below the modifiers tab) and put it in place. Give the fan a Lattice modifier and select the Lattice as the Object. Then give the Lattice a Shrinkwrap modifier with settings like the ones in the picture. Then set the cylinder as Target.
You also need the fan to have more geometry so that it can deform correctly. If it's a single mesh you can give it a remesh modfier set to Sharp. If it's not, you'll have to separate the parts, give and apply the Remesh modifier and then join them together again.

Thank you so much. I searched info about that and that was exactly what i was prettending to do.
